# Софт, который автоматически обустраивает java-среду

Tags: java, поиск-программ, инструменты-разработчика

Давненько от кого-то слышал, что какой-то парень написал софтину, которая обустраивает среду Java-девелоперу. Мол, ставишь себе такой галочки и через некоторое время получаешь готовую настроенную машину. Всякие Tomcat-ы, Eclips-ы, etc. Чтобы время не терять. Может, кто поможет вспомнить название? Был бы очень благодарен!